# how the right amount of threads are executed in CUDA

Tags: cuda

```
dim3 DimGrid((n-1)/256 + 1, 1, 1);
dim3 DimBlock(256, 1, 1);
vecAddKernel<<<DimGrid,DimBlock>>>(d_A, d_B, d_C, n);
__global__
void vecAddkernel(float* A, float* B, float* C, int n)
{
int i = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
if(i<n) C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
}
```

In the above function suppose we have vector of length n=257, we will have only 2 blocks assigned. I just wanted to know what happens in the second block when the vecAddkernel function is called. Is only one thread executed in the second block or all the 256 threads are executed though 255 of them have no output. So the basic question is how is parameter 'n' fixed for each vecAddKernel call? Is it 256 for every block or 256 for the first block and 1 for the second block?

Answer (score 4):

How many threads are executed in block is determined only by dimension of block, so 256 threads are executed though 255 of them have no "output". Also 'n' defines only dimension of grid and there are the same number of threads in the each block of grid.